# How to set rangeSelector min max dynamicly multiple times in angular highcharts?

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular-highcharts

I want to set the range of a angular highstock chart by clicking onanother component table or button.

Simple example, for selecting range T1 or T2 with setExtremes does not work:
(https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-49z46k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

In the next example I try to set the min max direct on the xAxis[0].min =value.
Sometimes it works twice but when you click multiple times it stops interacting.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update-5pd6yy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two mistakes in your code:

1. `this` in your chartCallback function points to a chart, use an arrow function to use component context.
2. `setExtremes` needs to be called on `this.chart.xAxis[0]`, not `this.chart.xAxis`

---

```
  chartCallback = (chart: Highcharts.Chart) => {
    this.chart = chart;
  }

  changeRange(min, max){
    this.chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
      min,
      max
    );
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dxjl2c

Comment: Thank you it works now. I don't really understand why it has to have arrow function to work.

Comment: Hi @Coen, That's because arrow functions have their own bindings to `this`. Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions